# CORS policy error despite configuring the recommended options in startup.cs

Tags: iis, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `.net core 5.0` web API which I am hosting on IIS. The front end is in Angular and is used for all the API requests.

Based on the documentation I have read to enable CORS, I have configured my `startup.cs` as below :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseCors(options =>
            options.WithOrigins(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ClientURL"].ToString()
            ).AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

<other stuff>

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

    services.AddCors();

}
```

and here's my appsettings.json file :

```
"ApplicationSettings": {
    "ClientURL": "http://localhost:4200"
  }
```

This configuration works as expected when I run the server through VS. But when I host this application in IIS, I get the error below :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:91/api/User/Login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

According to the documents on [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) by Microsoft, this should be enough. However, I still configured the web.config on the server hosting IIS as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebKeyMaster.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But this doesn't help my case either. Can someone please tell me if there's anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You need to understand that when hosting a site on IIS, CORS requests/responses do not only go through your web app. You can download and install IIS CORS module and allow it to assist, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could check your middleware's order to make sure the Calls the UseCors extension method and specifies the _myAllowSpecificOrigins CORS policy.   The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.

For more information, see [Middleware order.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order)

Comment: thank you, apparently the issue was with the placement of the CORS policy in startup file.

Comment: You mean you have other policy for the CORS inside the startup fileS?

Comment: no :) i meant other rules. like you said it needs to be between routing and authorization